# Few topological operations under which the classes of CDH-spaces

Tags: general-topology, homogeneous-spaces

It's known that $\mathbb{R}$ is a CDH space. Does anyone have any idea why $\omega^{\omega}$ is a CDH space? Then, Does anyone have any suggestion why $\mathbb{R}\times\omega^{\omega}$ is not a CDH space?

Also, the Cantor set $K$ in $[0,1]$ is CDH, and any compact metrizable space is continuous image of $K$. Then why this implies that continuous images of CDH-spaces need not be CDH?

Finally, note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not CDH, so the property of being CDH is not hereditary.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem $5.2$ of [this PDF](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-272-01/S0002-9947-1982-0656491-8/S0002-9947-1982-0656491-8.pdf) says that every topologically complete separable metric space that is strongly locally homogeneous is CDH. A space $X$ is strongly locally homogeneous if it has a base $\mathscr{B}$ such that if $x,y\in B\in\mathscr{B}$, there is an autohomeomorphism $h$ of $X$ such that $h(x)=y$, and $h(z)=z$ for all $z\in X\setminus B$. Since $\omega^\omega$ is strongly locally homogeneous, it is also CDH.

To see why $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ is not CDH, note that $\Bbb R$ is connected, $\omega^\omega$ is zero-dimensional, and autohomeomorphisms permute the connected components. The components of $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ are the sets $\Bbb R\times\{x\}$ for $x\in\omega^\omega$. If $D$ is a dense subset of $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ that has at most one point in each component, and $E$ is one that has more than one point in some component, there is no autohomeomorphism of $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ that sends $D$ to $E$.

Finally, $[0,1]$ is the continuous image of $K$ but is not CDH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you prove that $\omega^{\omega}$  is strongly locally homogeneous ?

Comment: @user987: You’re welcome. $\omega^\omega$ is homeomorphic to the irrationals. Let $$\mathscr{B}=\{(p,q)\setminus\Bbb Q:p,q\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<q\}\,.$$ Each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ is homeomorphic to the irrationals, which are homogeneous, so for any $x,y\in B$ there is an autohomeomorphism $h$ of $B$ taking $x$ to $y$. And $B$ is clopen, so $h$ can be extended to an autohomeomorphism of the irrationals by making it the identity map outside $B$.

Comment: Thanks Brian, in fact recently I was able to read the following "Let $X$ be a zero-dimensional space. Then homogeneity implies
   strongly locally homogeneous  " it can also help.

Comment: @user987: You’re welcome. And yes, that sounds like exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Hi, Brian, how do you prove that the set of irrationals numbers is a homogeneous space?

Comment: @user987: It’s probably a little easier to work with $\omega^\omega$ for that. If $x,y\in\omega^\omega$, for each $n\in\omega$ let $f_n:\omega\to\omega$ be the map that interchanges $x_n$ and $y_n$ and leaves everything else fixed. Let $h:\omega^\omega\to\omega^\omega:z\mapsto\langle f_n(z_n):n\in\omega\rangle$; then $h(x)=y$, and $h$ is an autohomeomorphism of $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I am new in homogeneity, For example, only I studied that the Cantor space $2^{\omega}$ is homogeneous, because is a topological group, and topological groups are homogeneous. Do you have any reference for homogeneity, SLH and CDH spaces?

Comment: @user987: You’re very welcome. I’ve never really worked with these properties, so I don’t offhand know of any good references. Some of the references in the paper to which I linked might be of some use, or some of the ones in [this PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0184.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the information Brian.

Comment: @user987: My pleasure. Good luck with it!

Comment: I have a new question, do you have any idea how to construct these countable dense subsets $D$ and $E$?

Comment: I was thinking of construct the sets as follows, choose a countable dense subset $D_{x}\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \{x\}$ for each $x\in\omega^{\omega}$ and define $D=\bigcup_{x\in\omega^{\omega}}D_{x}$. But D is not countable.

Comment: @user987: One countable dense subset of $\omega^\omega$ consists of all sequences that are eventually $0$, i.e., that have only a finite number of non-zero terms.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Scott. But my question was how construct the two countable dense subsets such that one meets at most one point Every component and the other has more than one point in some component.

Comment: @user987: Sorry, I misunderstood. $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ has a countable base $\{B_n:n\in\omega\}$ of sets of the form $U\times V$. Recursively choose points $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\in B_n$ so that the coordinates $y_n$ are all distinct. The resulting set $D$ is dense in $\Bbb R\times\omega^\omega$ and intersects each component in at most one point. To get $E$ just add one point from one of the components that intersect $D$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian Scott. I used your ideas and wrote an answer.

Comment: @user987: You’re welcome, and your answer looks fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brian Scott.

Comment: @user987: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Following the ideas of @Brian Scott we have the following

[image: productnocdh]